# Overloading Fail For Enumerator

Tags: c#

I want to implement a IEnumerator. But It causes a error

```
public class WachableDictionaryEnumerator : IEnumerator<TVal>
{
    private TVal[] a;
    private int len;
    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        len = len + 1;
        return len < a.Length;
    }
    public object Current
    {
        get
        {
            return a[len];
        }
    }
    public TVal Current
    {
        get
        {
            return a[len];
        }
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        a = null;
        len = 0;
    }
    public void Reset()
    {
        len = 0;
    }
}
```

The error is:

> Error 5   The type
>   'CPS.Manipulation.WatchableDictionary.WachableDictionaryEnumerator'
>   already contains a definition for 'Current'   D:\CE\Supins\Cyan Pembuat
>   Soal\Required Manipulation\Class1.cs  32  25  Required Manipulation

But if I delete one of Current object, then the error is

> Error 21  'CPS.Manipulation.WatchableDictionary.WachableDictionaryEnumerator'
>   does not implement interface member
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator.Current'.
>   'CPS.Manipulation.WatchableDictionary.WachableDictionaryEnumerator.Current'
>   cannot implement
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator.Current' because it does
>   not have the matching return type of 'TVal'.  D:\CE\Supins\Cyan Pembuat
>   Soal\Required Manipulation\Class1.cs  16  22  Required Manipulation

Help me to fix the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use [*explicit interface implementation*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173157.aspx) for one of either `IEnumerator.Current` or `IEnumerator<T>.Current`. Typically you implement the non-generic interface explicitly (where you need to), and make that implementation delegate to the generic one:

```
// Explicit interface implementation
object IEnumerator.Current { get { return Current; } }

// Normal implementation
public TVal Current { get { return a[len]; } }
```

Note that in order to get the *first* element correctly, you should initialize `len` to -1 to start with (and on `Reset`)... and ideally validate `len` in the `Current` property.

Note that when implementing `IEnumerable<T>` you need to do the same thing, e.g.

```
public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
{
    // Whatever
}

IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return GetEnumerator();
}
```